# Issue with inputting Japanese characters in edittext

Tags: android, unicode, input, internationalization, android-edittext

Some of our Japanese users are reporting that they are not able to change Hiragana to Kanji while inputting in the app from their keyboard. We are not familiar with Japanese at all and thus not able to understand what their problem exactly is.

Can the keyboard in Japanese mode covert Hiragana to Kanji automatically or is there some settings that we missed on?

Does the native keyboard even support Japanese input by own or you have to use some third party keyboard?

Is there some special settings you have to do or some font you need to include to support Japanese input in the app or Android handles it on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Japanese keyboard works similar to how spell checking works. The user types some hiragana which is underlined as they type and suggestions for kanji or katakana appear just above the keyboard typically. You can have a try by downloading the [Google Japanese Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.japanese&feature=search_result) app from Google Play and entering in some hiragana. I assume that this app is the default keyboard for Android devices in Japan.

I have not experienced that problem when dealing with Japanese characters in my development experience. I suggest downloading the input app, playing around and then investigating attributes on the EditText. Remember that Japanese is in unicode too so if it is breaking then other non-English languages probably are also.

Comment: I figured this one out and your are totally correct. Thanks a lot for the effort.